# Function overloading in C

Tags: c, posix, overloading

Today, looking at the man page for `open()`, I've noticed this function is 'overloaded':

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

I didn't thought it's possible on C. What's the 'trick' for achieving this ?

**LATER EDIT:**
So it's not really overloading, because when using varargs - you can only supply multiple arguments of the same type. So, is `mode_t` behind the scenes an int ?

Comment: mode_t is indeed an integer, but you can supply arguments of different types, assuming that you know how to interpret them.  The printf family of functions does this, using the format string to know how to interpret its extra arguments, even when they are differently typed.  My answer below has some examples which might clarify this.

Comment: @Eli thanks, i must have confused that with Java.

Comment: Functions like this are called variadic functions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's using [variable arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h). Those declarations appear only in the man page, as those 2 are the only ways you should call open(). The actual C function will be declared as e.g.

```
int open(const char *pathname,int flags,...);
```

With variable arguments, the arguments don't need to be the same type. `printf` is the obvious example of this.

In the case of open(), the first variable argument have to be mode_t if '`flags` contain the O_CREAT flag  because  implementation of open() expects it to be mode_t (which behind the scenes is likely an unsigned int or unsigned long - but that has nothing to do with varargs)

Answer (score 12):

C does make it possible to write function with a [variable number of argument](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html), such as `printf`.

With that being said, there is no reliable, cross-platform way in C to write a function that takes exactly 2 or 3 arguments; in general you must do something like

```
some_function(5, 6, 7, NULL);
some_function(5, 6, 8, 2, 5, NULL);
```

In other words, you must have a terminating "sentinal" argument.  Alternatively, you could include the number of parameters somehow in an earlier parameter, such as

```
another_func(2, "hello", "world");
another_func(3, "goodbye", "cruel", "world");
```

The `printf` family of functions take this approach; the first format parameter contains the number of extra parameter needed; e.g. with `printf("%f %f", 5.6, 7.11)` you know that there must be 2 float parameters.  However, this would be somewhat unsafe in a user-defined library function, since if you said `my_printf("%s %f %f %f %s", 5.6)` then you could get segfaults or worse.  Fortunately, most C compilers will check your calls to `printf` at compile time to avoid this kind of issue.

In the case of `open`, the function is declared as having variable arguments, and the third parameter is only checked if `O_CREAT` is set.  So this is how it "safely" determines whether a third argument is present.  I put "safely" in quotes because technically there's no way for open to know at runtime how many parameters were actually passed.  For example, the following calls would compile without any errors or warnings:

```
open("foo.txt", 5, "not an integer", 7);    // extra and invalid parameters
open("bar.txt", O_CREAT);                   // third parameter is missing
```

Comment: If `some_function()` takes `int`s, you shouldn't end it with `NULL`, as `NULL` is just 0 in numeric context. `NULL` terminators work best with pointer parameters.

Comment: @Chris: Good point, I generally use NULL as the terminator regardless of data types, but you're right that it might be confusing, especially to people who don't know that 0 and NULL are the same, since they might think they could write something like `some_func(3, 2, 1, 0, -1, NULL)` when in fact this would cause 0 to act as the terminating parameter.

Comment: Recent versions of gcc and the glibc headers together will produce a warning for your last two examples.

Answer (score 6):

"mode must be specified when O_CREAT is in the flags, and is ignored otherwise."

`extern int open (__const char *__file, int __oflag, ...)`

It uses `varargs` and only loads the mode variable argument if `__oflag` contains `O_CREAT`.

Answer (score 3):

very short answer - varargs

Comment: and knockoff the downvotes for correct answers - terseness is a virtue.

Answer (score 3):

you can fake it using variable arguments list with `...`

```
int function(int x, ...);
```